# Possible for Polish citizen to obtain US visa without employment?

Tags: visas, usa, polish-citizens

I visited Poland recently and met a Polish girl. I'd like her to come visit me in the United States for several weeks now. I understand she needs a visa to visit the US. The only problem is that she is unemployed and has been for over a year (she lives with her parents currently).

Is there a way she can still obtain a visa to visit the US despite her employment status?

Answer (score 5):

There is no specific requirement for her to have a job in Poland in order to visit the US. The most relevant information can be found on the [Nonimmigrant Visas page of the US Diplomatic Mission to Poland](http://poland.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas.html).

The most important thing is probably that she will need to demonstrate that she intends to return to Poland at the completion of her visit. This might be harder to show without a job, but it should still be possible.

A visitor to the US may be required to show proof of sufficient funds to cover their stay in the country. I don't know what this amount might be, or whether it will be required for somebody from Poland staying for a couple of weeks. The best approach for her would be to start the online application process and see what questions it asks.

If the application asks what the purpose of the visit is, I would suggest keeping the answer simple, such as "Visiting a friend" rather than "I met the love of my life and I'm going to the US to live with him for several weeks".

Comment: Would it be acceptable if I am the one funding her during her stay in the US?

Comment: Some countries allow a citizen to submit a formal affidavit of sponsorship along with somebody else's visa application (this reduces the amount of funds required on arrival). However, I'm afraid I don't know whether the US has something similar, it wasn't obvious when I had a look at the US visa site (and the DS-160 application is online rather than being a PDF one can download and read).